# Redux store does not have a valid reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

Haven't been able to find anything around here regarding this error:

> "Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers."

My reducer

```
export default function FriendListReducer(state = {friends : []}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_FRIEND':
      return [
        { friends : action.payload.friend }, ...state.friends
      ]     
    default:
      return state;
  }
  return state;
}
```

Combiner

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { FriendListReducer } from './FriendListReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  friends: FriendListReducer
});
export default rootReducer;
```

My store config

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState = { friends: [] }) {
  const logger = createLogger({
    collapsed: true,
    predicate: () =>
    process.env.NODE_ENV === `development`, // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  });

  const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, logger);

  const store = middleware(createStore)(rootReducer, initialState);

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers/reducers', () => {
      const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers/reducers').default;
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Your `import` statement is incorrect. Either you use `import { Foo } from 'bar'` together with `export Foo`, *or* use `import Foo from 'bar'` if you export with `export default Foo`.

In other words, change either `export default function FriendListReducer` to `export function FriendListReducer`, or change the import statement from `import { FriendListReducer }` to `import FriendListReducer`.

Comment: Ah an easy miss, in my case it was automatically added by VS Code...

Answer (score 35):

If the object is empty.

```
 export  default  combineReducers({

 })
```

This error will show.

Answer (score 9):

../reducers/reducers ? it's a strange naming

Anyway, it seems ../reducers/reducers doesn't return a reducer, if reducers is a directory, put a index.js inside, import each reducer and create a root reducer

```
import FriendListReducer from "./FriendListReducer"

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   friendList : FriendListReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

> **Important!!** *you will have state.friendList in your state.*

I hope it will help

Answer (score 4):

**store.js**

**FALSE**

- import { charactersSlice } from "./charactersSlice.js";

**TRUE** *NOT USING {}*

- import charactersSlice from "./charactersSlice.js";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your top-level reducer function is using an array as its default value.  Redux expects that the very top of your state will be an object, not an array.  Try putting the array at a particular key in that object, like `{ friendList : [] }`.

Comment: Your "initialState" value you're passing to the store doesn't matching the structure you're creating using `combineReducers`.  You're giving `combineReducers` a field named `FriendListReducer`, but the store initial state has `friends`.  You need to make those match one way or the other.  Since they don't match, you've still got the same problem.

Comment: I've updated the code and still getting the same error, updated code here

Answer (score 0):

on above your codes

```
import { FriendListReducer } from './FriendListReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  friends: FriendListReducer
});
export default rootReducer;
```

instead of `import { FriendListReducer } from './FriendListReducer';`

just say `import  FriendListReducer  from './FriendListReducer';`

since `FriendListReducer` was exported with `export default FriendListReducer` and not `export const FriendListReducer`

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error because of the wrong import
**import { tasksSlice } from "./TaskSlice";**

**Right Way**

Then, I did the import like **import tasksSlice from "./TaskSlice";**

Answer (score -1):

```
Please check your combine reducer file It's empty......

you have forgot bind reducer here

import {combineReducers, createStore} from 'redux'
import listDataReducer from '../reducers/ListDataReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    listDataReducer,         //  Please add your reducer here
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the problem.
What I did was instead of:

```
combineReducers(productReducer, cartReducer)
```

I did:

```
combineReducers({ productReducer, cartReducer })
```

and it worked.
It expects a valid object for the store.