# Store does not have a valid reducer. react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having the problem above, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407937/redux-store-does-not-have-a-valid-reducer), but no luck.

here's my store:

```
import { compose, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import * as activities from "../reducers/activities";
import * as location from "../reducers/location";

const configureStore = railsProps => {
  const composedStore = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  );

  const combinedReducers = combineReducers({
    location,
    activities
  });
  return composedStore(createStore)(combinedReducers, railsProps);
};

export default configureStore;
```

here's my location reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import * as actions from "../constants/constants";

const coordinates = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.GET_LOCATION_SUCCESS:
    case actions.GET_LOCATION_REQUEST:
    case actions.GET_LOCATION_FAILURE:
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const reducer = coordinates;

export default reducer;
```

here's my activities reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import * as actions from "../constants/constants";

const page = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.NEXT_ACTIVITY_PAGE:
      return action.page < action.totalPages - 1
        ? action.page + 1
        : action.page;
    case actions.PREV_ACTIVITY_PAGE:
      return action.page > 0 ? action.page - 1 : 0;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const activities = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.FETCH_ACTIVITIES_SUCCESS: {
      return state.concat(action.activities);
    }
    case actions.FETCH_ACTIVITIES_REQUEST:

    case actions.FETCH_ACTIVITIES_FAILURE:

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const reducer = combineReducers({ page, activities });

export default reducer;
```

I guess it has something to do with the combineReducers method and how I import stuff, but I'm not sure what's wrong there.

Thanks

Comment: From http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html maybe you should replace `import * as location from "../reducers/location";` with `import location from "../reducers/location";` (there's a note in the page linked about that import statement under the `arguments` section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
import * as activities from "../reducers/activities";
import * as location from "../reducers/location";
```

above would export all the named exports from the file while your reducers are default exports.

**correct:**

```
import activities from "../reducers/activities";
import location from "../reducers/location";
```

EDIT:

if you want to export reducers from the file make them named:

```
export const page = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
  }
};

export const activities = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
  }
};
```

and later:

```
import { page, activities } from 'path/to/file.js';
```

Comment: in my activities file I have a `page` and a `activities` reducer does this mean that I should have them all on separate files?

Comment: Do it when you feel like managing them would be better in separate files.

Comment: but how can I do otherwise, when I can have only one `export default` per file, and need to export `page` and `activities`?