# Invalid Reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

**Orignal Error Msg:**

> Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to
>   combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.

Here is the:  **reducer.js**

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import list_reducer from './reducers/list_reducer.js';


export default combineReducers({
  list_reducer
});
```

Here is the: **list_reducer.js**

```js
const list_reducer = (state = {
  operation: 'success',
  userlist: []
}, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_USER_FULFILLED":
      return {
        ...state,
        userlist: state.userlist.concat(...action.payload)
      }


    case "UPDATE_USER_DETAILS_FULFILLED":
      return {
        ...state,
        userlist: state.userlist.concat(...action.payload)
      }


    case "DELETE_USER_FULFILLED":
      return {
        ...state,
        userlist: state.userlist.concat(...action.payload)
      }


    case "REGISTER_USER_FULFILLED":
      return {
        ...state,
        userlist: state.userlist.concat(...action.payload)
      }


  }

};

export default list_reducer;
```

Tried Everything from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407937/redux-store-does-not-have-a-valid-reducer)

Have been stuck on this error for quite a while now and I am on clock so any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE: HERE IS WHAT CONSOLE.LOG(list_reducer) looks like from reducer.js**

list_reducer

list_reducer

```
 function list_reducer() {
    var _state$userlist, _state$userlist2, _state$userlist3, _state$userlist4;

    var state = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : { operation: 'success', userlist: [] };
    var action = arguments[1];


    switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCH_USER_FULFILLED":
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                userlist: (_state$userlist = state.userlist).concat.apply(_state$userlist, _toConsumableArray(action.payload))
            });

        case "UPDATE_USER_DETAILS_FULFILLED":
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                userlist: (_state$userlist2 = state.userlist).concat.apply(_state$userlist2, _toConsumableArray(action.payload))
            });

        case "DELETE_USER_FULFILLED":
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                userlist: (_state$userlist3 = state.userlist).concat.apply(_state$userlist3, _toConsumableArray(action.payload))
            });

        case "REGISTER_USER_FULFILLED":
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                userlist: (_state$userlist4 = state.userlist).concat.apply(_state$userlist4, _toConsumableArray(action.payload))
            });

        default:
            return Object.assign({}, state);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code when you use your main reducers file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it seems that you're using `combineReducers` several times, which can produce such error. Review carefully your imports of **reducer.js** file and check whether it passed into another `combineReducer` function.

Comment: Yup there was another combineReducer inside store.js file thanks mate you solved my hours of frustation.

Answer (score 2):

You always needs to return `state` in your `default` case:

```
default:
  return state;
```

Otherwise unknown actions will cause the state to become `undefined`. Redux checks for this case and throws an error. Remember that all the top-level reducers are going to run for *every* action type, not just the ones it has cases for. Read more in [the docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions).

Comment: Yeah, you probably haven't reached this yet, it sounds like your reducer isn't importing at all. What bundler are you using? What do you get if you `console.log(list_reducer)`